# D:\file\file1\SVN how to get folder path?

Tags: c#, filepath

`D:\Saran\Software\SVN`    this is mypath. How to get only `SVN` in c#?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
string myFileName = Path.GetFileName( @"D:\Saran\Software\SVN" );
```

myFileName will now contain the string `"SVN"`.

See the [System.IO.Path docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) for all the functions, and examples, this class provides.

Comment: I added a link to the MSDN docs for Path, hope that's okay. _(Sorry my keyboard can't make the character in your name)_

Comment: @Wesley Werner: You can select and copy name :)

Comment: @Wesley - That is perfect! Sorry to bother you with norwegian characters ;)

Comment: @Øyvind that is true! When I start a comment I always try press tab to auto-complete user names, just like in xchat :p

Answer (score 0):

I did just that about ten minutes ago! If you have TortoiseSVN, create a directory, right-click on Windows Explorer and select "SVN Checkout..."

For url, give file:\d\Saran\Software\SVN. Then you get content of the subversion repository.